# Need a vb equivalent on a declaration of list of tasks

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, list, task

Im looking at an example at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx , but need a vb equivalent of the code below. I've tried all sorts but not getting any luck. Below is the code im stuck on converting.

```
var tasks = new[] {  
Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(_ => 3), 
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_ => 1),  
Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(_ => 2), 
Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(_ => 5), 
Task.Delay(4000).ContinueWith(_ => 4),
```

};

Comment: What are you continuing with, exactly?

Comment: Well the example is returning an integer, and seems to be a lambda expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have a compiler handy to make sure, but I think this should get you very close:

```
Dim tasks =
    { Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(Function(_) 3),
      Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(Function(_) 1),
      Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(Function(_) 2),
      Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(Function(_) 5),
      Task.Delay(4000).ContinueWith(Function(_) 4),
    }
```

This is using the new [array type inference syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee358704.aspx) and [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx).